# How can I get the package name of data copied to clipboard?

Tags: android, kotlin, clipboard

I need to get package name of data copied to clipboard. For example, I just want to use copied data from **com.example.customApp**. So is it possible to can that? If possible, how can I do this?

Thanks for helps.